# what is this error (Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. )

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, angular-cli

the error printing on the console is below one... i am trying to add a form by add employee buton

Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("    
        ][(ngModel)]="model.name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">

[here is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw3N6.png)

the below is the code of it

```
<div class = "container">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>Add Employee:</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" 
name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name"
placeholder="Enter Your Name">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="position">Position:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" 
name="position" [(ngModel)]="model.position"
placeholder="Enter your position">

</div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="salary">Salary:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="salary" 
name="salary" [(ngModel)]="model.salary" 
placeholder="Enter Salary">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">  
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" click)="addEmployee">Add 
Employee</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<h2>Employee Details</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width=400>Name</th>
<th width=400>Position</th>
<th width=400>Salary</th>
<th width=200>Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
enter code here
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let employee of employees; let i=index">
<td>{{employee.name}}</td>
<td>{{employee.position}}</td>
<td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
</tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: solved my issue by adding import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; and @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
,FormsModule  ]    in app.module.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved my issue by adding import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; and @NgModule({ declarations: [ AppComponent ], imports: [ BrowserModule ,FormsModule ] in app.module.ts